# Error `script class cannot be found` when trying to add a camera change component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this pops up when I try to add the script to the gameobject like in the tuturial: [image: 1]

> Can't add script component 'CameraChange' because the script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors and that the file name and class name match.

How do I fix this? Here is the tuturial that I am following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nR5P7AH4aHE&t=106s&ab_channel=JimmyVegas

Comment: Can you share your CameraChange script please

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that there are no compiling errors.
Second, this error is most common when class name inside `.cs` file is not matching file name. Make sure class name perfectly matches file name, case-sensitive. Or class is not inherited from Component or MonoBehaviour.
Correct minimal file content for CameraChange.cs would be:

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraChange : MonoBehaviour
{

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you it was changing the monobehavior to camera change